# Accessing individual lines in a large CSV file quickly in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I need to access individual lines in a CSV file with around 42,000 lines in ruby.

I'm aware of '`Foreach()`' however, this is still too slow, and I need something that doesn't load the entire CSV to memory (I think this is what is slowing it down).

I was using Python and '`linecache.getline()`' worked well, is there something similar in ruby? Thanks!

Comment: I made good experience with copying the data into a sqlite-DB and select from there.  This may be a solution, if you have many access on an unchanged csv.

Comment: Well, if you have to read arbitrary lines the file much more often than you add new ones there you could try the following: 1) read the file and build an index where for each line number you keep two numbers (starting point and length) and then 2) use lower level-machinery (`IO#seek`/`IO#pos`/`IO#read`) to position and read the necessary line(s) only without iteration over all of them.